# Converting Date from '01-JAN-85' format to MySQL readable in table (from Postgres)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, phpmyadmin

I have a set of code that I'm coverting from Postgres to work on MySQL (PHPmyAdmin) which already has a section of inserts in the following type of format:

```
INSERT INTO ORD (TOTAL, SHIPDATE, ORDID, ORDERDATE, CUSTID, COMMPLAN)
VALUES ('101.4', '08-JAN-87', '610', '07-JAN-87', '101', 'A');
```

Since MySQL doesn't like the date as '08-JAN-87' it just ends up displaying 0000-00-00 in the date columns.

From the searches I've done so far the only solutions given seem to be converting it during the select statement so it displays correctly. I would like to know a method of changing the data itself. (not just a select statement)

This is for a uni assignment and the lecturer could only advise manually changing all the insert statments to a format it will accept. This might work for this case but in the long run or for a larger data dump this won't be possible.

Comment: In what format is the data stored?

Comment: 08-JAN-87 is not the way that Postgres store date data, so where are you getting it from? Postgres will accept that format for date input but needs the datestyle parameter correctly set to avoid the ambiguity between YMD and DMY. ie 12-JAN-02 could be 12 Jan 2002 or 2 Jan 2012.

Comment: @Shadow Declared as 'DATE' format during create table step.

Comment: @DavidSoussan It's just the way the code was for pre-loading. Postgres could handle and display it fine. Now we're to port the code over to MySQL and fix as needed.

Comment: check this link if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404875/change-date-format-that-mysql-reads , you may convert the date format using sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the import so that the data string is converted for MySQL

```
INSERT INTO ORD (TOTAL, SHIPDATE, ORDID, ORDERDATE, CUSTID, COMMPLAN)
VALUES ('101.4', STR_TO_DATE('08-JAN-87', '%d-%b-%y'), '610', STR_TO_DATE('07-JAN-87', '%d-%b-%y'), '101', 'A');
```

This tells mysql that the string 08-JAN-87 is a date in the format DD-MMM-YY and to convert it to a valid date datatype.

Comment: As mentioned above I was trying to avoid having to change all the insert statements as this would not be practical should the error arise for an even larger number of records. But if this is the only way then I shall make it work! The STR_TO_DATE would be easier to copy/paste in comparison to changing them all myself also so thank you.

Comment: Well, you could use a regex to do it for you, either in a script or in your IDE. All depends on how many there are.